# ROS node subscription not connected

Tags: c++, c, ros, robotics

I am using a rosbag to publish on various topics and i am trying to get my sample program to allow one node to subscribe to those topics via class method functions. But nothing is being printed out on console for the subscribers. I tried roswtf and i got

```
 WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /roscpp_pcl_example:
 * /camera/depth/points
```

Here is my program code and i am not sure where the problem lies. These are my reference for the API https://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

```
// Include the ROS library
#include <ros/ros.h>

// Include pcl
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

// Include PointCloud2 message
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

// Topics
static const std::string SUB_TOPIC_1 = "/ecu_pcl";
static const std::string SUB_TOPIC_2 = "/velodyne_back/velodyne_points";
static const std::string SUB_TOPIC_3 = "/velodyne_center/velodyne_points";
static const std::string SUB_TOPIC_4 = "/velodyne_front/velodyne_points"


//define class with member functions for callback usage
//allows for subscription of various topics in the same node
class callback_node{
    public:

    void callback1(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg->data.c_str());
    }

    void callback2(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg->data.c_str());
    }

    void callback3(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg->data.c_str());
    }

    void callback4(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
    {
      ROS_INFO_STREAM(msg->data.c_str());
    }

    

};

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize the ROS Node "roscpp_pcl_example"
    ros::init (argc, argv, "roscpp_pcl_example");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    callback_node callback_obj;
    // Print "Hello" message with node name to the terminal and ROS log file
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hello from ROS Node: " << ros::this_node::getName());

    // Create ROS Subscribers to SUB_TOPIC with a queue_size of 1000 and a callback function via class methods
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = nh.subscribe(SUB_TOPIC_1, 1000, &callback_node::callback1, &callback_obj);
    ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe(SUB_TOPIC_2, 1000, &callback_node::callback2, &callback_obj);
    ros::Subscriber sub3 = nh.subscribe(SUB_TOPIC_3, 1000, &callback_node::callback3, &callback_obj);
    ros::Subscriber sub4 = nh.subscribe(SUB_TOPIC_4, 1000, &callback_node::callback4, &callback_obj);


    // Spin
    ros::spin();

    // Success
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that immediately jumps to my eye is that you have actually put `std_msgs::String::ConstPtr` as the topic type but have topics `/ecu_pcl` and `/velodyne_points` which should not be of type `std_msgs::String` but instead should have a different data types, point clouds I assume, so something like **[`sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)**. Therefore you would have to modify the callbacks to their correct data types, e.g. `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr`.

What surprises me as well is the message `roswtf` gives you:

```
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
  * /roscpp_pcl_example:
    * /camera/depth/points
```

This means that your node `roscpp_pcl_example` is subscribed to a topic `/camera/depth/points` nobody is actually publishing. Yet your code snippet does not mention `/camera/depth/points`. (Are you only showing part of the node's source code or have you forgotten to recompile the code with `catkin build`?)

---

Anyways in order to debug it try the following:

- Make sure you have sourced the correct workspace by executing **`$ source devel/setup.bash`** in each console you open for the following steps
- Open a console and browse the `rosbag` that you want to play and execute **`$ rosbag info <filename.bag>`** and check in the output. Make sure that all the topics you need for your node have actually been recorded!
- If that is the case continue to play it with **`$ rostopic play <filename.bag>`**.
- Now check if all topics are published correctly by opening a new console, sourcing the workspace and typing **`$ rostopic list`**.
- Then check out the type of each individual topic from this list with **`$ rostopic info <topicname>`**.
- Finally make sure that you use the **correct topic type for your subscribers**. You might need to update your `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` accordingly!

Comment: actually after sourcing and catkin_make, i am still getting that stubborn /camera/depth/points which makes no sense. Previously i may have done something with it but i have already done a catkin_make and it shouldn't be there

Comment: I am not sure if there is another way of clean rebuilding that i am not aware of but i just created a new pkg to run and it does not contain that camera topic

Comment: In such a case you could try to call `catkin_make clean`  to clean the workspace. This should remove all previously build code. But glad it worked this way!